# How can I add my python plugin's symbolic icons to the hicolor dir and use them?

Tags: python, launcher, icons, budgie

I am developing [my Budgie applet](https://github.com/serdarsen/budgie-browser-profile-launcher) based on [this budgie python example](https://github.com/budgie-desktop/budgie-desktop-examples/tree/master/python_project).

I would like to use symbolic icons for the applet, but how do I apply them?

I tried saving and using my icons to `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/symbolic/apps` or `/usr/share/icons`, `..hicolor/scalable/actions` manually but the plugin didn't recognise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### About symbolic icons

Symbolic icons are (mostly) `.svg` icons, of which the name looks like:

```
some-icon-symbolic.svg
```

The special advantage of symbolic icons is that you can set its color, even if the icon itself has a totally different color. Therefore, they can ideally be used in themed situations, like panel icons.

*An example:*

Say I have an orange (symbolic) icon `foldertrack-symbolic.svg` icon:

[image]

Normally, this icon, used in a panel would look like:

[image]

When applied as a symbolic icon however, it fits in the theme:

[image]

#### How to apply symbolic icons to use its advantages

**Don't** set the image by its path (including extension):

(Don't use this ↓)

```
icon = Gtk.Image.new_from_file(
    "/usr/share/pixmaps/foldertrack-symbolic.svg",
)
```

But:

- Make sure the icon is in a directory where you can simply use its icon name (by default you can use `/usr/share/pixmaps`, as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles))
- Set the image by (only) its name *without extension*, and set the desired [icon size](https://people.gnome.org/%7Egcampagna/docs/Gtk-3.0/Gtk.IconSize.html):

```
icon = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name(
    "foldertrack-symbolic", Gtk.IconSize.MENU
)
```

...and your icon nicely fits in :)

[image]

#### The .plugin file

It won't surprise you can use the exact same trick on the .plugin file, to make the applet's appearance in Budgie-Settings fit in:

Use in the Icon description the name of the symbolic icon:

```
Icon=foldertrack-symbolic
```

...and it will fit in perfectly:

[image]